# Why is blur function running on android chrome as soon as I click an input?

Tags: android, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a text input and label, wrapped in a div. When the div wrap is clicked, a class is added to the child label to fade it a bit. On blur, the class is removed. This works fine in the browser, but on my mobile, as soon as I click the input, the class is added, then immediately removed. Why is this?

My jquery looks like this:

```
// listen for taps
$('.inputWrap').on('touchend',function(e){

    $(this).children('input,textarea').focus();
    $(this).children('label').addClass('ready');

});

// hide the label altogether once typing begins    
$('input,textarea').on('keypress',function(){

    $(this).prev('label').hide();

});

// on blur, check if the input is empty, if so, show the label again 
$('input,textarea').on('blur',function(){

    if($(this).val() == '')
    {
        $(this).prev('label').show().removeClass('ready');
    }

});
```

[Here is a jsfiddle of it *not* working on mobile.](http://jsfiddle.net/zfXfS/3/) If you change that 'touchend' to a click, it works on desktop and mobile ok, but this needs to be a touch action.

Comment: What is the point of covering the input field with a div, catching the touch, applying a css property and then removing it when on blur event is fired?

I would expect them to happen relatively quickly and result is something the user would never see.

Comment: Theoretically, when you click the label, it focuses on the input. This adds a style to the label so that it fades out slightly, so that the user isn't completely blind to what the field is for, in case they forget. The blur function only fires if they have deselected the input and they didn't type anything, so that the visual returns to the default.

Comment: Why don't you set a :focus state to fade it out, rather than catch the touch event and then rather than listen for the blur event, you'll just go back to the origin css without :focus state properties.

Comment: This seems too simple to satisfy my self sabotaging need for complexity.